# How to find an interval over which f is increasing/decreasing at an increasing/decreasing rate?

Tags: calculus

I'm in Calculus 1, and I'm asked the following questions:

Given the graph of the function $f(x)=5x^3-3x^5$:

Using the EXACT values for zeros of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ identify intervals in the domain where:

$f$ is increasing at an increasing rate over: (EDIT: I think the answer is $(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$)

$f$ is increasing at a decreasing rate over: (EDIT: I think the answer is $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$)

$f$ is decreasing at an increasing rate over: (EDIT: I think the answer is $(-infinity,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$)

$f$ is decreasing at a decreasing rate over: (EDIT: I think the answer is $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},infinity)$)

I'm also asked to find local extrema, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there.

I've already determined $f'(x)=15x^2-15x^4$ and $f''(x)=30x-60x^3$, that's easy, and the zeros of the first derivative are $x=-1, x=0, x=1$; and the zeros of the second derivative are $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, x=0, x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I've also determined the inflection points to be $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{7}{4\sqrt{2}}), (0,0), and (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{7}{4\sqrt{2}})$ by substituting the zeros of the second derivative into the original $f(x)$ function.

I'm stuck on the "increasing at an increasing rate" and subsequent other ones as well. Any tips would be appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT: I've tried my hand at the answers but I'm not sure if they're correct.

Comment: Any interval where (for example) the first and second derivative are both positive represents an interval where the function is strictly increasing, at a strictly increasing rate.

Comment: Increasing/decreasing: derivative, increasing rate/decreasing rate: second derivative.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that $\ f\ $ is increasing over intervals where $\ f'\ge0\ $ and decreasing  over intervals where $\ f'\le0\ $, and $\ f'\ $ is increasing over intervals where $\ f''\ge0\ $ and decreasing  over intervals where $\ f''\le0\ $.  Combining these observations we have:

1. Over intervals where $\ f'\ge0\ $ and $\ f''\ge0\ $, $\ f\ $ will be increasing at an increasing rate;
2. Over intervals where $\ f'\ge0\ $ and $\ f''\le 0\ $, $\ f\ $ will be increasing at a decreasing rate;
3. Over intervals where $\ f'\le0\ $ and $\ f''\ge0\ $, $\ f\ $ will be decreasing at a decreasing rate;
4. Over intervals where $\ f'\le0\ $ and $\ f''\le0\ $, $\ f\ $ will be decreasing at an increasing rate;

Since condition $1$ holds over the interval $\ \left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ $, you're correct that $\ f\ $ is increasing at an increasing rate there (you could also include the end points in the interval if you wish).  However you've missed the fact that this condition also holds over the interval $\ \left(-1,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ $, so $\ f\ $ is also *increasing* at an increasing rate over that interval rather than *decreasing* at an increasing rate as you state in your third answer.

Since condition 3 holds over the interval $\ \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right)\ $ and nowhere else other than the interval $\ \left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\,\right]\ $, your second answer, that $\ f\ $ is decreasing at a decreasing rate over that interval is also correct.

Your remaining answers aren't correct.  To fix them, simply determine the signs of $\ f'\ $ and $\ f''\ $ over the remaining intervals $\ (-\infty,-1\,]\ $, $\ \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\,\right]\ $ and $\ [\,1,\infty)\ $ with limits at the zeroes of $\ f'\ $ and $\ f''\ $  and look up the answer in the list given above.